# Darkmode toggle not working on firefox and mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox, mobile

I'm editing my tumblr theme to include a dark/light mode toggle and I have encountered a few problems that i have no idea how to solve.
The following code is what I have put inside the $(document).ready(function(){}) function.

```
   var mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
   var modetoggle = document.getElementById("modetoggle");
   var toggleicon = document.getElementById("toggleicon");
   
    if (mode) {
        $('body').addClass(mode);
        
        $('div.normalmode').on("click tap touchstart", function(){
         $('body').toggleClass('day');
         localStorage.setItem('mode', 'day');
         toggleicon.toggle('la-sun'); 
         toggleicon.toggle('la-moon');
         modetoggle.classList.add('nightmode');
         modetoggle.classList.remove('normalmode');
        });
        $("div.nightmode").on("click tap touchstart", function() {
         $("body").removeClass("day");
         localStorage.setItem('mode', null);
         toggleicon.toggle('la-moon');
         toggleicon.toggle('la-sun');
         modetoggle.classList.add('normalmode');
         modetoggle.classList.remove('nightmode');
        });

        if ($('body').hasClass('day')) {
         toggleicon.toggle('la-sun');
         toggleicon.toggle('la-moon');
        }
    
        else {
         toggleicon.toggle('la-moon');
         toggleicon.toggle('la-sun');
        }
    }
    
    $(".tag-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).parents("article").find(".indextags").slideToggle(500);
    });
```

Then this code is my html:

```
<nav id="radio">
    <label title="day/night">
        <div class="normalmode" id="modetoggle"><span class="las la-sun" id="toggleicon"></span></div>
    </label>
</nav>
```

For chrome the span class icon toggle does not work, I cannot get it to get a moon appear when it's in light mode and a sun when it's in dark mode. (it just stays a sun the whole time).
I did manage to do this with an opacity solution, but that one definitely did not work in Firefox and also not in responsive systems as it relies on a fixed position for the toggle.

For Firefox and mobile devices, clicking the icon does not change the theme colors and I guess that also means it won't change the body class at all.

I have been breaking my head over what's causing this problem, I've changed functions to include tap and touchstart, I've changed code to be more explicit (and i feel like it's all become redundant).

Am I doing anything wrong?